# How to get rid of blank lines generated by Python 3 CSV writer on Linux

Tags: python, linux, csv

I'm trying to write a CSV file with data generated from the analysis of video frames. First I collect the metadata of each video in an array (*vid_data*), which is then appended to a bigger list of all the videos' metadata (*data*_*list*). After that, I need to write two more columns: contractions and time intervals at which they happen.

```py
def writing_to_cvs():

    # open the file in 'writing' mode
    with open("output.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:

        # create a writer object
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, lineterminator='\n')

        # write out the headers for the columns of the CSV file
        writer.writerow(["Video filename","Duration","FrameRate","NumFrames","Height","Width","Contractions","TimeIntervals"])

        # using a two-dimensional list where
        # every sublist represents a row in the CSV
        #print("the row:", data_list)

        for vid_data in data_list:
            writer.writerow(vid_data)

        for contra in contractions_list:
            for c in contra:
                writer.writerow([''] * 6 + [c])

        for inter in time_intervals:
            #print('time:', inter)
            writer.writerow([''] * 7 + [inter])
```

My issue is that each time writerow is called, it leaves blank rows between that and the last time it was called. The resulting CSV file is this:

[image]

Any idea on how to get rid of those blank lines?

I've already tried using the newline='' and the lineterminator='\n' but it didn't change anything. I've read in other similar posts that it could be related to the OS (I'm using Linux), but haven't found specific advice addressing that other than adding newline='' for Windows users.

Also, for info I'm using Python 3.10.

Comment: The problem  is your code, in particular `writer.writerow([''] * 6 + [c])` ` and `writer.writerow([''] * 7 + [inter])`. You are creating a new row each time you call these and offsetting the column by the `([''] * <n>`. You need to add `c` and `inter` to `vid_data` and write that out to a row.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver But would I be able to write them as full columns instead of rows? That was my initial issue.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a nested structure with `vid_data` and then `c` and `inter` under that. CSV is not a nested structure format. It is line formatted, where each line is a complete 'unit' of data.  Still if you want to do this then you need to combine `c` and `inter` into a list with the desired offset and then write the list out to a  row.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver if I didn't want any offset and wanted c and inter's data to be written into the columns G and H (not a single row), is there any way to go about it using a CSV file and csv.writer or is there a better alternative to that?